# How to have a new activity start with the action bar not visible using a theme?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Why doesn't this style I have result in the action bar not being displayed?

My activity is descended from appcompat. I assume these are all the correct properties.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

it is taking effect, cause the status bar gets removed. But the action bar doesn't seem to get affected.

I can still successfully remove the action bar like this:

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends AppCompatActivity {



       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                getSupportActionBar().hide();

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_screen);
```

but i have to admit I'm a little bit disappointed that I can't do it from xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your manifest? Where do you associate the theme with the activity?
Try something like this:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme" />
>
> <style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
>     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/cobalt_light</item>
>     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/cobalt</item>
>     <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/cobalt_lighter</item>
>
>     <item name="colorAccent">@color/cobalt_light</item>
> </style>
> </resources>
> ```

You dont need to extends from parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

Comment: you were right that switching to inheriting from theme.appcompat.light.noactionbar fixes it. But i don't understand why setting these properties in a theme:

  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

doesn't also remove the action bar. I would expect windowactionbar false to remove the action bar.

Comment: I guess the parent style overwrite the attribute... but It's hard to say